# When do lone pairs on nitrogen contribute to aromaticity?

Tags: organic-chemistry, heterocyclic-compounds, aromaticity

[image: 1,2,4-trimethyl-1H-imidazole]

I've been told that 1,2,4-trimethyl-1⁠*H*-imidazole is aromatic. As it has four obvious pi electrons (in the double bonds), I assumed that it was anti-aromatic as opposed to aromatic.

I've been operating under the assumption that a nitrogen does not contribute its pi electrons to the aromaticity count for Hückel's rule unless it is attached to a hydrogen. Does the nitrogen with a methyl group here donate its pi electrons to the count?

Answer (score 13):

[image: 1,2,4-trimethyl-1H-imidazole]

Both nitrogens in your drawing are roughly $\mathrm{sp^2}$ hybridized, therefore they each have a p-orbital and 3 $\mathrm{sp^2}$ hybdridized orbitals. All of the p-orbitals, including those on the 3 carbon atoms in the double bonds, are perpendicular to the plane of the screen (*e.g.* they project above and below the plane of the screen). So there are 5 p-orbitals and each contains one electron **except** for the one p-orbital located on your "bottom" nitrogen (in green). This p-orbital contains the nitrogen lone pair, so there are two electrons in this p-orbital.

If we count the p-electrons we have $1+1+1+1+2 = 6$ electrons in $5$ p-orbitals that form a continuous loop. Therefore, the molecule is aromatic ($4n+2, n=1$).

Let's take a closer look at the "top" nitrogen in your drawing (in purple). Where is its lone pair? It resides in an $\mathrm{sp^2}$ orbital on this nitrogen. The $\mathrm{sp^2}$ orbital lies in the plane of the screen. This orbital is orthogonal (perpendicular) to the 5 p-orbitals; therefore these 2 lone pair electrons are separated from the electrons that make the molecule aromatic. They are not involved in the molecule's aromaticity.

Here's how to approach this situation in the future:

1. Identify the nitrogen(s)
2. Determine if the lone pair is in a p-orbital or an $\ce{sp^2}$ orbital.

   - If the nitrogen is in a double bond, then the lone pair is in one $\ce{sp^2}$ orbital, 1 electron is in the p-orbital and 1 electron is in each of the 2 remaining $\ce{sp^2}$ orbitals.
   - If the nitrogen is not in a double bond, then the lone pair is in a p-orbital and 1 electron is in each of the 3 $\ce{sp^2}$ orbitals.
3. Count the electrons in the cyclic p-orbitals to determine aromaticity

Answer (score 4):

The nitrogen with a methyl group does indeed contribute to aromaticity in this molecule. The criteria for aromaticity under Hückel's rule are that $4n+2$ electrons reside in coplanar p-orbitals in a cyclic system. This allows the p-orbitals to overlap and form a set of π-orbitals, which are delocalised over the whole ring system.

In this example all the atoms in the ring are sp<sup>2</sup> hybridised. The three carbons in the ring form three σ bonds with their sp<sup>2</sup> orbitals and then have one half-filled p-orbital perpendicular to the plane of the ring which participates in π-bonding.

The nitrogen with a double bond forms two σ bonds with two of its sp<sup>2</sup> orbitals and uses the third to accommodate its lone pair. The lone pair is therefore in the plane of the ring, facing outwards, and is thus unable to participate in π-bonding. It is left with a half-filled p-orbital in the plane which contributes another electron to the π-system.

The nitrogen with the methyl group attached forms three σ bonds with its sp<sup>2</sup> orbitals, and therefore has a full p-orbital remaining perpendicular to the plane of the ring, which can overlap with the other p-orbitals to form a π-system.

In total there are six π-electrons residing in five coplanar p-orbitals. So, Hückel's rule is fulfilled and aromaticity is present.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a crude, qualitative method:

Note that on top, delocalizing the electrons from that particular nitrogen results in a resonance contributor that has an $\ce{sp}$ hybridized nitrogen. $\ce{sp}$ hybridization implies a linear bond angle (180 degrees). Do you think we can get anywhere close to a linear bond angle in a 5-membered ring of all things? Remember, in resonance contributors the nuclei don't move. It's just the electrons that are "moving" (delocalized).

In the bottom I try to delocalize the electrons from the other nitrogen. This is fine, as the resulting resonance contributor now has an $\ce{sp^2}$ nitrogen. Note that this does *not* mean that the nitrogen in the ring is exactly $\ce{sp^2}$. It's likely somewhere in between $\ce{sp^3}$ and $\ce{sp^2}$. A more or less $\ce{sp^2}$ atom in a 5-membered ring is more plausible than a $\ce{sp}$ atom. So we can conclude that it's this nitrogen's lone pairs that are delocalized throughout the ring. Incidentally, this makes for 6 pi electrons. Additionally, the other Huckel rules are fulfilled (even the planar requirement; both nitrogens have $\ce{sp^2}$ character so they're more or less planar). So we can conclude this molecule is aromatic.

[image: Resonance structures of imidazole]

Comment: Leads to the correct result, but the reasoning is faulty (I know you said it is crude). The lone pair on the "pyridine-type" nitrogen (at the top) is orthogonal to the pi system, and that is why resonance does not take place, not because the resulting resonance structure is too unstable.