# Determining aromaticity of compounds

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromaticity

> Which of the following planar structures would be aromatic?

[image: molecules]

Could someone help me determining the aromaticity of the compounds?

My Attempt:

(i) Not an aromatic compound since it only has 4 pi electrons that does not satisfy Hückel's (4n+2) rule.

(ii) Not aromatic because it only has 4 pi electrons, however I'm not sure if the oxygen contributes a p-orbital, but it shouldn't matter since 5 pi electrons still does not satisfy Hückel's rule.

(iii) I'm very confused because I'm not sure if the ketones are considered "part of the ring" therefore do they also contribute p orbitals? However if we ignore the ketones, then I believe the Nitrogens contribute 2 e- since they are sp2 hybridized? Therefore the 2 N atoms and 2 C atoms contribute a total of 4-not aromatic either?

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/27099/when-does-nitrogen-contribute-its-electrons-to-aromaticity

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(i) that's correct

(ii) is aromatic, it fit's the 4n+2 rule with n=1.  Here is a drawing of furan showing 2 lone pair electrons in a p-orbital that completes the cyclic aromatic ring. Furan's other lone pair of electrons is perpendicular to the pi system and does not play a role in furan's aromaticity.

[image]

([image source](http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Organic_Chemistry/Hydrocarbons/Aromatics/Properties_of_Aromatics/Aromaticity/H%C3%BCckel's_Rule))

(iii) Edit to incorporate @jerepierre's comment:

Just like phenol can exist in equilibrium with its **non-aromatic** tautomeric keto form

[image]

so can derivatives of pyrimidinedione (or uracil).  However, unlike phenol were the equilibrium lies far to the aromatic phenol side, these compounds usually (it depends on the substituents) exist in the keto form.  The strength of the keto and amide bonds outweigh the weaker aromaticity of the pyrimidine skeleton and shift the equilibrium to the keto side.

[image]

([image source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uracil))

The question remains, **is the keto form aromatic**?  As jerepierre points out, you can draw the following resonance structure for the keto form.  In this double-dipolar resonance structure there are 6 pi electrons 2 in the double bond and 2 [a lone pair] on each nitrogen) suggesting that this resonance structure would be aromatic.  Since this resonance structure contributes to the overall description of the molecule, it would be fair to say that this molecule has some aromatic character; certainly not as much as benzene or furan - but some.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure about the uracil. Cyclohexadienone is clearly non-aromatic because of the sp3 center. Uracil is fully conjugated, and you can draw an aromatic resonance structure of uracil. I suspect that makes it aromatic, but one could argue either way.

Comment: @jerepierre  I agree, it could be argued either way, not a good question.

Comment: i also thought that the ketone substituents didn't influence aromaticity either

Comment: @jerepierre I think those structures are rather too minor contributors, but one would need experimental data to determine this for certain.

Comment: @Nerdingout check this: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/22100/what-is-the-resonance-structure-of-nitro-aminobenzene-with-a-broken-aromaticity

Comment: but wait wouldnt (iii) be aromatic due to the 2 pi electrons from the double bond + 2 electrons from each nitrogen (4) = 6?

Comment: Yes, isn't that what I wrote?

Comment: you said (iii) is non-aromatic

Comment: I said that the keto form of phenol isnon-aromatic, I said (iii) is a romantic

Comment: Okay that makes more sense!! Also last question-so the ketone substituent does not influence aromaticity?

Comment: It does influence aromaticity.  It is only because we can draw the dipolar resonance form of the ketone that the molecule can be considered aromatic

Comment: I would again like to point out, that aromaticity is a feature, that correctly can only be obtained from experiments. Lewis structures, even resonance structures can only explain, why there is a ring current, not predict if there is. Hückel's rule is a nice guideline for an ad hoc chemical assumption, but it can hardly be treated as a law. For what it's worth, aromaticity is simply defined, as "having a chemistry typified by benzene". http://goldbook.iupac.org/A00441.html