# Is 2-pyrone an aromatic compound?

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, heterocyclic-compounds, aromaticity

I was told by my professor that α-pyrone is not an aromatic compound, but I count two π-electrons as well as one of the lone pairs on oxygen giving six total which would be one of Hückel's $4n + 2$ numbers. Does the carbonyl contribute to aromaticity?

[image: 2H-Pyran-2-one]

Comment: Not everything that follows the 4n+2 rule is aromatic ... not to mention this rule is not so hot when we have a pendant pi-bonding atom.

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/15272/is-tropone-aromatic

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/101265/aromaticity-of-heterocyclic-compound

Comment: The second one particularity for this link https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja00750a055

Answer (score 3):

[This answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/163991/17175) discusses this situation in connection with the closely related 2-pyridone. The $4n+2$ rule does not apply at all when there are pendant pi-bonding atoms, but in the case of a carbonyl oxygen atom (with its high electronegativity) we can consider a contributing structure where the carbonyl pi bond is polarized towards oxygen: $\ce{\overset{+}{C} -\overset{-}{O}}$. If this polarization leaves a ring satisfying the $4n+2$ rule, this zwitterion becomes a significant contributing structure and the molecule will show aromatic characteristics.

In the case of $2$-pyrone the zwitterion structure leaves six pi electrons in the conjugated ring and thus an aromatic contribution is expected. The [proton nmr spectrum[1]](https://www.chemicalbook.com/SpectrumEN_504-31-4_1HNMR.htm) shows proton NMR shifts greater than that in ethylene and closer to that in benzene, indicating aromatic character. At the same time [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-Pyrone) reports that 2-pyrone

> may participate in a variety of cycloaddition reactions to form bicyclic lactones. For example, it readily undergoes Diels-Alder reactions with alkynes producing, upon loss of carbon dioxide, substituted benzenes.[2]

Thus the compound has mixed aromatic and aliphatic characteristics, a common occurrence with molecules having an aromatic-zwitterion contribution from a pendant carbonyl oxygen.

**References**

1. Pirkle,W.H. & Dines,M. (1069). _J.Heterocyl. Chem. 6, 1 (1969).
2. Woodard BT, Posner G H (1999). "Recent Advances in Diels-Alder Cycloadditions Using 2-Pyrones". *Advances in Cycloaddition*. 5: 47–83.