# Still struggling with Huckel rule and aromaticity

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds

I'm still learning huckel rule and aromaticity in different compound.
For the 1-methoxy-1,3,5,7-octatetraene, is it correct that it has 8 electrons inside the cycle, but since they will be 8, then it is antiaromatic?

And for the Imidazole, is it 6 electron inside because the N: doesn't contribute to the pi, or is it 8?

[image]

Comment: Why would someone downvote a question? I'm new here in chemistry.stackexchange and I'm still learning...can someone explain?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/27099/when-do-lone-pairs-on-nitrogen-contribute-to-aromaticity https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/33332/why-is-cyclooctatetraene-non-planar-but-the-cyclooctatetraenide-anion-planar

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there are two parts to the question, and both are duplicates (see Mithoron's comment). If this were just one question, we could close it as a duplicate, but because there are two, we can't.

Comment: I'm voting otherwise.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Advice**

Take a closer look at the lone pairs and double bonds that participate *only and only* in the delocalization of electrons.

**1-methoxy-1,3,5,7-octatetraene**

As you can see, 1-methoxy-1,3,5,7-octatetraene has four double bonds in an octagonal cycle. The lone pairs of the adjacent oxygen atoms, even though they directly influence the delocalization by means of the resonance effect, aren't actually part of the cycle and cannot be included amongst the pi electrons of the double bonds. Therefore, your molecule is antiaromatic. Its structure is not planar, in fact it looks something like this (the picture below includes only the cyclic backbone):
[image]

For aromatic molecules, planarity is absolutely necessary. But Huckel's rule which I'm sure you're familiar with, provides the reasoning behind the planarity of the molecule.

**The imidazole**

As for the imidazole, your assumption is absolutely correct. Here we get to know a scenario similar to pyridine:
[image]

The lone pair does not participate in the aromatic cycle. This can be easily checked by taking a look at the hybridization of the nitrogen atom. If the lone pair were to be part of the aromatic system, it should have been *perpendicular* to the other orbitals of the cycle. However, this is not the case. The ***2p*** orbitals of the nitrogen are actually involved in the aromatic cycle, while the aforementioned paired electrons get to be embedded in an ***sp2*** orbital, placed perpendicular to the plane of the cycle. This actually has significant consequences on the basicity of pyridine.
On the other hand, in order not to interrupt the aromatic cycle, the lone pairs of the other nitrogen atos must come into play when counting pi electrons. Thus, the molecule is aromatic.

Comment: Thank you @TheRelentlessNucleophile I just want to make sure for 1-methoxy-1,3,5,7-octatetraene it is nonaromatic, not antiaromatic (because antiaromatic should retain planar feature), and it is nonaromatic because it is not flat like the figure shows.

Comment: In case of 1-methoxy-1,3,5,7-octatetraene, the answer would be zero for the number of electron, right? because since it not planar, then it conjugation will be accounted from because resonance is not happening anymore, please correct me if I'm wrong? @TheRelentlessNucleophile

Comment: @user432797 Yes you're right.

Comment: I turned out that @TheRelentlessNucleophile is right in everything even with antiaromatic categorization

Comment: Apologies, I didn't see the comments you had posted after my answer. If a molecule has an uninterrupted network of pi electrons and 4n pi electrons, it is usually antiaromatic. Because they lack the stabilization that would otherwise be present in the aromatic molecules thanks to the pi orbital that delocalizes over the whole molecule (see Huckel's rule), the molecule stabilizes itself by adopting non-planar configurations.

Comment: Rule of thumb: uninterrupted network of pi electrons, planar molecule, 4n+2 electrons, extended pi orbital that delocalizes over the whole molecule: aromatic. Violate one rule and the molecule is rendered either antiaromatic (4n pi electrons) or non-aromatic. Now, I lack the appropriate knowledge to tell you exactly why do we bother with antiaromatic molecules in the first place, but let's just say that, as far as I know, if you were to draw the Frost circles in a Huckel diagram, their HOMOs would be at the ground energy level, rendering the orbitals non-bonding.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that several of these molecules prefer to exist as diradicals, instead of completely stable molecules

Comment: thank you @TheRelentlessNucleophile ! Can you refer me to the reference that you used? I still don't get why my question was downvoted!

Comment: Your question was downvoted becausw it looked like homework and also because of lack of details involving YOUR work in answering the question ans sharing YOUR knowledge. Please refer to the rules of ChemSE.